# Rails Algolia 404 Index Does Not Exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, algolia

I'm trying to set up Algolia in a Rails 4 app with the following code, as per their instructions.

`algoliasearch.rb`:

```
AlgoliaSearch.configuration = { application_id: "my_id", api_key: "my_api" }
```

and

`job.rb`:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  include AlgoliaSearch

  algoliasearch do
    attribute :title
  end

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments

  validates :title, :description, :company, :url, :logo, presence: true

end
```

Using these settings I'm able to connect to Algolia just fine but when I call `Job.reindex` in the rails console I get the following error:

```
2.2.0 :002 > Job.reindex
[algoliasearch-rails] Cannot GET to https://my_id-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/Job.tmp/settings?getVersion=2: {"message":"Index does not exist","status":404} (404)
Job Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "jobs".* FROM "jobs"  ORDER BY "jobs"."id" ASC LIMIT 1000
=> nil
```

There are sample Jobs in the database and when I look at my Algolia dashboard I can see that the records have been uploaded so not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't have`@raise_on_error` to true, you can consider this just as a log. There is [an issue about this on GitHub](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-rails/issues/120).

> Yeah, that's actually a side-effect of the logging mechanism; we call get_settings on this non-existing-yet temporary index; I fixed it yesterday in 52a19a8; will be part of the next release.